# Hibernate many to many relationship to save only association in join table

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I have two entities in hibernate (MySQL database storage) which are related many to many. 
These are "Project" and "Category".

Project <---> Category

I have a join table named "project_category" to join these entities stored in "project" and "category" tables. The join table stores only primary keys from these tables. These keys are "project_id" and "category_id".

I have fixed number of Categories. Category table is already populated with possible list of categories for the projects. When new project is created, it belongs to one or more categories and that is stored in

In my mapping for "Project" class I have specified many to many navigation from Project to Category using "project_category" table which is as follows:

```
<set name="categories" table="project_category" fetch="join" cascade="persist">
   <key column="project_Id" />
   <many-to-many column="category_Id" class="Category"/>
</set>
```

This is what I want to achieve..

I want to save the Project and associated categories (here I don't want to create any new category just associate the category_id with my project_id). Categories already exist and I want to use them whenever new Project is saved.

In code, I have created a collection of desired categories (out of many categories that I have in Category table) and added to Project instance and trying to save the Project using hibernate. Now expecting project_category to contain association of project and categories.

I am observing that while saving Project, hibernate trying to Category (which is not what I want because I already have category created - I want to just associate it with my new project).

What kind of mapping need to achieve above goal?

I read this good article but here author is creating both entities rather than using already created one.
http://technicalmumbojumbo.wordpress.com/2007/09/25/investigating-hibernate-associations-many-to-many/

Answer (score 0):

If the categories already exist, then you should not create new instances. You should get them from the database, using the Hibernate session.

If you have the IDs of the categories you need to associate with a new project, and you don't want to issue a select query to get thosee categories from the database (because there is no way these categories aren't in database anymore), then simply use the `Session.load()` method:

```
Set<Long> categoryIds = ...;
for (Long categoryId : categoryIds) {
    Category category = (Category) session.load(Category.class, categoryId);
    newProduct.add(category);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Actually the problem was with .persist() call. I changed it to .save() and it worked. Don't know why it was trying to insert in to Categories table.

Comment: you have a cascade=persist in your mapping, but no cascade=save.

Answer (score 0):

When categories already exists in Database, you just set **cascade to none**. Many to Many configuration for Project and category as follow :

```
<set name="categories" table="project_category" fetch="join" cascade="none">
      <key column="project_Id" />
      <many-to-many column="category_Id" class="Category"/>
</set>
```

From this configuration hibernate insert in project and project_category table only.